# F#: Accessing UI Elements from storyboard in ViewController?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, f#, xamarin.ios

New to F# here and trying to build a Xamarin.iOS app in pure F#. In C# when I place a UI element in the Storyboard editor and name it, and in the storyboard references the controller, I am able to access the UI element in that controller.
i.e. I have a button called MyButton I created in storyboard. Now in the controller I want to add an action, let's say create an alert, in C# I might write

```
MyButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
...
}
```

I'm trying to do the same in F# but it doesn't recognize "MyButton" in the controller. Any help?

Update: I did some research and as usual most of the source are several years old. The way that C# is able to reference objects from the designer is through the project template producing associated YourController.designer.cs files that reference objects from the designer. This is a partial class. According to this interesting blog post:

http://7sharpnine.com/2013/02/03/2013-02-03-monotouch-and-fsharp-part-i/

, this feature is not availabe in F# because, "The lack of partial classes in F# makes the tooling available for UI designer a pain to integrate tightly into F#", he claimed he'd be working on it however that blog post is from 4.5 years ago so I'm hoping someone has fixed this... Please Advise

Update2: The same blog came back 4 years later and addressed the issue again
http://7sharpnine.com/2017/04/11/i-want-to-tell-you-a-storyboard/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a UIButton defined on your ViewController named "fsharpButton" you define an `Outlet` that obtains the VC object reference and assigns it to a mutable at runtime then you can wire up the touch events.

```
let mutable _fsharpButton = null :> UIButton

[<Outlet>] 
member this.fsharpButton
       with get() = _fsharpButton
       and set value = _fsharpButton <- value
```

Complete ViewController example:

```
namespace ios_fsharp_foo

open System
open Foundation
open UIKit

[<Register ("ViewController")>]
type ViewController (handle:IntPtr) =
    inherit UIViewController (handle)

    let mutable _fsharpButton = null :> UIButton

    let addUpdateHandler =
        new EventHandler (fun sender eventargs ->
            Console.WriteLine("Hello StackOverflow")
    ) 

    [<Outlet>] 
    member this.fsharpButton
           with get() = _fsharpButton
           and set value = _fsharpButton <- value

    override x.DidReceiveMemoryWarning () =
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.

    override x.ViewDidLoad () =
        base.ViewDidLoad ()
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        _fsharpButton.TouchUpInside.AddHandler addUpdateHandler

    override x.ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (toInterfaceOrientation) =
        // Return true for supported orientations
        if UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom = UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone then
           toInterfaceOrientation <> UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown
        else
           true
```

Personally I just create the UI via code and skip Storyboard designer...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I linked to a blog that described a new type provider for F# for UI's, it links to a github. Do you know how to install it from there it's just a paket? I can't find it in the Nuget Library. Should I make a seperate question?
https://github.com/xamarin/fsharp-iOS-designer
it's located there, how could I install it into my project to use the Xamarin.UIProvider? I'll try your method as well. I don't understand how it knows what this.fsharpbutton is in your example, wish I could understand it also...

Comment: @Zee I do not now if it was every released via Nuget, I played with it very briefly awhile back, just load up the `Xamarin.iOSProviders.sln` solution and compile the `Xamarin.UIProvider.iOSRuntime` project, add that library to your Xamarin.iOS project... FYI: His website (`http://7sharpnine.com`) is down... `fsharpbutton` is defined as the `UIButton` name in the `.storyboard`, the `Outlet` attribute defines the connection between the code and the UIButton that gets inflated/instanced when the `.storyboard` is loaded.

Comment: @Zee  Xamarin has a guide that explains ObjC outlets, its in C# and uses Xcode to define the outlets instead of Xamarin iOS designer, but it will show you how the connections are made and what is happening in the background: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/ios-ui/creating-ui-objects/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why in F# are the functions called as x.[name of function] is x some sort of instance of a UI instance? In C# they are just declared as functions as part of the class, not instances. Probably something to do with functional programming which I haven't fully grasped yet

Answer (score 1):

Some evil genius made a workaround with type providers. Pretty good stuff! Sorry for those sad souls who had to code before april 2017! mwhahaha!

http://7sharpnine.com/2017/04/11/i-want-to-tell-you-a-storyboard/